# Is it possible to share one MAC address for multi ports of Linux bridge

Tags: linux-networking

I am working on a project. There are multi ports(NICs) bridged to the Linux bridge. We want to use one MAC address for multi ports and bridge to save MAC address.Is it possible? Actually, I have done some test and it seems OK. But I am not sure if there are some potential issues that I don't know. For example, is there performance issue? I know Linux bridge address learning should avoid flooding,but I still want you can share your opinions in case I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to do things. The bridge itself doesn't have any MAC address at all. Why should it -- it can't originate packets and you can't send packets to it. Typically, the host that is implementing the bridge is also a device connected to the bridged network, that virtual device needs a MAC address since it can originate Ethernet packets and Ethernet packets can be sent to it.

Comment: David, yes,in our case the host implementing the bridge is assigned an IP address on the bridge interface.It can originate Ethernet packets and Ethernet packets can be sent to it. We will use one MAC address for mulit ports of Linux bridge.Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: You shouldn't think of it as using one MAC address for multi ports of the bridge. The bridge doesn't have any MAC address -- it's not a station, it's not a device packets can be send from or to but just pass through. The machine that implements the bridge has one MAC address on the Ethernet network, just as other devices connected to the bridge ports physically do. It's just not physically connected to the bridge but virtually connected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and pointing out the subtle misunderstanding.